# Will I lose my data if I downgrade to 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, downgrade

So I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and I am having A LOT of problems!!!
I have decided to go back to 14.04 LTS through my CD.. So I just wanted to know if I will lose my apps and settings if I downgrade using the CD, because basically I will be reinstalling 14.04 if I do so.. If yes, is there any other way to downgrade without losing my settings?

Comment: you can keep your apps and settings intact, but in order to install it you will need internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

The application you are looking for is `aptik`. With this app you can backup yout current `application` **LIST**, `ppa` and their settings. You cannot backup your installed applications. But, since you backed up your application list and their settings, so, next time when you restore your applications, it will download all the previously installed applications, restore your ppas and apply the previous settings on them.

Comment: Thanks! As a noob I like to have a GUI app to help me out

Comment: Aptik is a gui application

Comment: That's what I said... I love it when there's a GUI application to help me out

Comment: Well, if it solves your issue, then could you please accept the answer.

Comment: @HrijulBhatnagar - :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will lose your data if you reinstall 14.04. And no, there's no proper way of keeping your software. I recommend you to backup your files to an external drive and take note of all the programs you installed with APT (you can get a list of them with the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`). After reinstalling, get your files back from the external drive and install your apps again (I recommend doing it from the terminal, it will be faster with `sudo apt-get install package 1 package 2 package 3 ...`).

Comment: So would it be better if I just waited for 16.04 LTS and upgraded with the software updater? (I don't have a lot of time since I am in 10th grade and have to study)

Comment: No. That's probably the reason why your 15.04 installation is messed up: upgrading from the software updater. Never do it; it usually leaves you with a system full of bugs. I always recommend people to make fresh installs if they want to upgrade. If you don't have much time why don't you stick with a rolling release distribution? You will never have to upgrade anymore. You may like Arch Linux, but since its installation is text-based and a little complicated, I recommend Manjaro (based on Arch).

Comment: Oh! Ok, I'll stick with ubuntu and will get a fresh install of 16.04 once its out....
Actually, I am a 100% windows user who just HAD TO shift to linux because my old laptop is so weak that it can't even get windows to work smooth... So, I decided to install ubuntu which had a good UI and seemed lightweight... Unless you can suggest another OS which is noob-friendly, has a nice UI, and is more stable than ubuntu...

Comment: Xubuntu is VERY smooth and customizable (pretty beautiful, too). After using Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10, Lubuntu 15.04, Arch Linux and openSUSE 13.2 XFCE I can tell Xubuntu 14.04 (which I am using as single and main system right now) was the best of all. It runs with 180 MB of RAM memory and it's highly customizable, you can make it look the way you want, create panels, move them around, add/remove panel items... The list is big. It is very user-friendly, too, and I can say you won't want to stick with Windows anymore (I deleted Windows from my PC after 1 week using Xubuntu).

Comment: Thanks.. I checked out some YouTube videos on Xubuntu and its pretty awesome considering the amount of customizations I can do... I currently have unity and mate desktop environments installed... Is there any way I can replace them with Xubuntu without doing a fresh install?

Comment: Yes, but I must warn you that removing other Desktop Environments is a little difficult and you won't have the full Xubuntu experience. You can either install the package `xubuntu-desktop` that comes with all the recommended packages or `xubuntu-core`, that comes with the bare bones (Xfce, xfce4-terminal, Thunar file manager, etc.) with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-core`.

Comment: To remove unity, use `sudo apt-get remove unity unity-asset-pool unity-control-centerunity-control-center-signon unity-gtk-module-common unity-lens* unity-services unity-settings-daemon unity-webapps* unity-voice-service`

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you installed ubuntu in the first place. If you made a seperate partition for /home you will lose nothing. Though, by default ubuntu installs /root & /home in same partition. You can check with`gparted` whether /home is on same or different partition (i.e. sda followed by different number). If in doubt, post image here

Comment: How do I post  an image in the comments?